# How to get first element in array in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I tried to get only first element [0] of array and print in UI.
I will get only first lesson in the array and then print.

```
{route.params.Lessons.map((lessons) => {
              return (
                <View>
                  <Text style={styles.lessonTitle}>Lesson 1</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.lessonDescription}>{lessons.lessonName}</Text>
                </View>
              )
            })}
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you elaborate on the issue?

Comment: can you add your expected result?

Comment: why don't you create an object of arrays?

Comment: @Dylan, Get only First lesson name

Comment: you want to display only the first element of array [0] instead all of them?

Comment: @Dylan, Yes....

Comment: Did you try ``route.params.Lessons[0]?.lessonName``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to display only one element of array, you don't need to use the `.map()` function

You can try this instead

```js
const lesson1 = route.params.Lessons[0]

return (
    <View>
        <Text style={styles.lessonTitle}>Lesson 1</Text>
        <Text style={styles.lessonDescription}>{lesson1.lessonName}</Text>
    </View>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this code:

```
<View>
  <Text style={styles.lessonTitle}>Lesson 1</Text>
  <Text style={styles.lessonDescription}>{route.params.Lessons[0].lessonName}</Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply solved!

```
const LessonList = route.params.Lessons;

return (
    <View>
        <Text style={styles.lessonTitle}>Lesson 1</Text>
        <Text style={styles.lessonDescription}>{Lessons[0].lessonName}</Text>
    </View>
       )
```

I hope you find an answer :D